# Forcing DTO properties along the path in ServiceStack

Tags: routes, servicestack

I have some DTO class with boolean field IsLocked.

It's easy to build route like

```
/.../{IsLocked}
```

and it will assign this field to query value.

But I need something like

```
/.../lock
/.../unlock
```

and that is to assing IsLocked field forcibly to true or to false depending on the route.

Can I do that without CustomRequestBinder and without parsing Request.RawUrl?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like 2 different operations so I'd look at declaring 2 operations, e.g:

```
[Route("/files/{FileName}/lock")]
public class LockFile { ... }

[Route("/files/{FileName}/unlock")]
public class UnlockFile { ... }
```

Otherwise you can declare the routes as normal and return a computed boolean property comparing the string, e.g:

```
[Route("/files/{FileName}/{LockString}")]
public class LockOrUnlockFile 
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string LockString { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get { return LockString == "lock"; } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It's implemented as one operation ChangeLockedState(bool locked), but customer want 2 different paths in API like lock & unlock. And it also useful for another method wich takes enum parameter status, and customer want one path to input enum value (/.../{Status}) and completely different path to assing fixed enum value (something like /.../newfiles, and DTO not contains that field). The second way - that decision, but is there any other way?

Comment: There is the overloaded method Routes.Add in AppHost wich takes the propertyExpressions parameter. I guess it can help, but I don't understand how it works and I found no information about it. It is also possible to help me {ignore} keyword, but on this subject is also very little information.

Comment: @VladimirShiyanov `{ignore}` is just matching an empty placeholder, see docs in [matching ignored paths](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#matching-ignored-paths). Here's an [example usage of propertyExpressions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/cb4eb92a9029b841e352fbd1c5d97ec75939b488/tests/ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Tests/Routes/ServiceRoutesTests.cs#L104), i.e. it only provides a way to use a typed property expression to map to property names.